# Using env variables in YML with default value

Tags: go

I have the following code to read config files from yml which includes ENV variables too:

```golang
confContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile("config.yml")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // expand environment variables
    confContent = []byte(os.ExpandEnv(string(confContent)))
    conf := &SysConfig{}
    if err := yaml.Unmarshal(confContent, conf); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

`config.yml`

```
db:
  name: ${DB_NAME:qm}
  host: localhost
```

It is working but how can I get it to read default values if `DB_NAME` env is not given?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace the mapper on `ExpandEnv` using `Expand` and take into account default values like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    mapper := func(placeholderName string) string {
        split := strings.Split(placeholderName, ":")
        defValue := ""
        if len(split) == 2 {
            placeholderName = split[0]
            defValue = split[1]
        }

        val, ok := os.LookupEnv(placeholderName)
        if !ok {
            return defValue
        }

        return val
    }

    os.Setenv("DAY_PART", "morning")

    fmt.Println(os.Expand("Good ${DAY_PART:test}, ${NAME:Gopher}", mapper))
}
```

this will render

```
Good morning, Gopher
```

This is based on the [example from Expand](https://pkg.go.dev/os#example-Expand) from the os package documentation.

Comment: `split := strings.Split(placeholderName, ":", 2)` is probably better as it solves the possibility of having a `:` in your value

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use the awesome [Viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) package by [spf13](https://github.com/spf13)) to read conf files, it can solve your problem gracefully and you can use it to load many other type of conf files.

### Solve your problem

1. Get the package

```
    go get github.com/spf13/viper
```

2. conf file

Supposed you have conf file named `db.yaml`:

```yaml
db:
  name: somedb
  host: localhost
```

3. code example

As we can see, once Viper loads the conf file, we can get values by key. A Yaml file will be parsed as a nested structure which you can unmarshal into a Golang struct, We should use `viper.GetString("db.name")` to get the value, you can refer to [this page](https://github.com/spf13/viper#accessing-nested-keys) to get more usage info.

```golang
import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

func InitConf() {
    viper.AutomaticEnv()     // read system env 
    viper.SetConfigName("db")  // conf file name to be load
    viper.AddConfigPath(".")    // conf file path

    viper.SetDefault("db.name", "mysqldb") // you can set default da name value here 

    // do read conf file and handle error
    if err := viper.ReadInConfig(); err != nil {
        if _, ok := err.(viper.ConfigFileNotFoundError); ok {
            // Config file not found; ignore error if desired
        } else {
            // Config file was found but another error was produced
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("db.name: %s", viper.GetString("db.name"))
}
```

`viper.AutomaticEnv()` this method will read system env automatically, suppose you have an env named `ENV_XXX`, then you can get it by `viper.GetString("ENV_XXX")`. **If the env name is the same as one of conf file key, viper uses the env first**

- when we do not set the `name` in `db.yaml` the output will be `db.name: mysqldb`
- when we set the `name` value: `somedb` in db.yaml the output will be `db.name: somedb`

Hope you will find it useful! more details on usage see the [Viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) README file

Answer (score 0):

I guess you had a struct for your *conf* like this:

```
Db *struct{
        Name string
        Host string
    }
```

so for retrieve the default variable of Dbname, you must check it like this:

```
if conf.Db == nil || conf.Db.Name == "" {
        conf.Db.Name = "test"
    }
```